Proving that Every Riemannian manifold of dim=1 is locally isometric to Euclidean space
My try:
Let's prove that every 1-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ is  locally isometric to the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric $g_0=dt^2$.
Consider a Riemannian metric $g$ on a 1-dimensional manifold $M$. In local coordinates $x$, the metric can be expressed as:
$$
g = f(x) \, dx^2,
$$
where $f(x) > 0$ is a smooth, positive function.
To construct a local isometry $\varphi$ from $(M,g)$to $(\mathbb{R}, dt^2)$, we define a new coordinate $t(x)$ representing the arc length from a reference point $x_0$ to $x$ along the manifold:
$$
t(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \sqrt{f(u)} \, du.
$$
This is a valid and smooth definition since $f(x)>0$ ensures that $f(x)$ is smooth and positive.
Differentiate $t(x)$ with respect to $x$:
$$
\frac{dt}{dx} = \sqrt{f(x)}.
$$
Thus, we have:
$$
dx = \frac{dt}{\sqrt{f(x)}}.
$$
Substitute the expression for $dx$ into the metric $g$:
$$
 g = f(x) \, dx^2 = f(x) \left( \frac{dt}{\sqrt{f(x)}} \right)^2 = f(x) \cdot \frac{dt^2}{f(x)} = dt^2.
$$
Thus, the metric in terms of the new coordinate $t$ is:$ g = dt^2$, so
$$
t(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \sqrt{f(u)} \, du
$$
is the local isometry that I was looking for, so define $\varphi(x):=t(x)$ for a generic vector fields $X=c(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $Y=d(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\varphi^*(g_0)(X,Y)=g_0(d\varphi(X),d \varphi(Y))=g_0(X\varphi,Y\varphi)=g_0(c(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\varphi,d(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\varphi)$
$=g_0(c(x)\varphi'(x),d(x)\varphi'(x))=c(x)d(x)g_0(\varphi'(x),\varphi'(x))=c(x)d(x)(\varphi '(x))^2 = c(x)d(x)(\sqrt(f(x))^2$
$=g(c(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x},d(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=g(X,Y)$, ie $\varphi^*(g_0)=g$
I would appreciate your feedback. I found a similar solution here Riemannian 1-manifold is flat by Balloon, but it looked more involved to me, at the end the author takes the inverse of the same map that I called $t(x)$ and composes it with the chart to define the local isometry. I don't see why that is necessary, if it can we done like I did provided it is correct. If it is not, please tell me why my approach does not work. I also find it a bit suspicious that I am not explicitely using the chart diffeomorphism , although I did stated  the metric g is given on local coordinates. I guess the chart is x itself. I am not sure my t(x) is really locally mapping $M$ to  $\Bbb R$, it looks to me that it locally maps  $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$

What is the definition of a flat space?

@ArcticChar  Riemannian manifold is said to be ﬂat if it is locally isometric to Euclidean space. I'd better leave out the word flat

FWIW, I would have stopped at the line establishing $g = \cdots = dt^{2}$, which to me shows $g$ is Euclidean in the coordinate $t$.
